# Overriding node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl problems

Tags: views, theming

Hello i am trying to override a node view without much success. I dont know if its just the syntax for my view thats wrong.

When i go to theme information the Row Style output tpl suggestion is

views-view-row-node--taxonomy-term--page-3.tpl.php

i can override that fine but it suggests it would be better to overide node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php

So i have a tpl file named

node-view-taxonomy-term-page-3.tpl.php

but it doesnt seem to want to override. Am i missing maybe a '-' somewhere in the tpl title?

I am using Views 3 and D6. I have the tpl in the same folder as my node.tpl.php

all help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Obligatory CTFC comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: sorry aendrew yes i have cleared the cache a few times but to no avail. thanks

Comment: Some more info would be helpful -- what are you wanting to do? views-view-row-* does something much differently than node-view-taxonomy-term-*: the former themes a View row, the latter themes a taxonomy term page.

Comment: thanks for the reply aendrew. I want to theme the node output on one of my taxonomy views. You can view the view here http://onlinebanter.com/blogs I am trying to theme the Page: Theming information (row style) as with my theme the node view is a bit odd as you can see. Its geared towards the frontpage. I was hoping to make the 'node' full width in this view and not as it is. Im sorry if i sound a little confused as i am :(

Comment: What suggests it would be better to override Reg?

Comment: When i go to Theme Information in the view itself Alex under Row style output: views-view-row-node.tpl.php it says in there "Rather than doing anything with this particular template, it is more
 * efficient to use a variant of the node.tpl.php based upon the view,
 * which will be named node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php. "

Comment: and its that node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php that i cannnot override. Sorry if i am not being the most helpfull its just after 6 years at drupal im finally starting to get to grips with it. I just want to override the node tpl for this view and this view only. Have it full width etc with a teaser etc. tx

Comment: Reg, can you try the code below to see what templates are on offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to see what your available theme suggestions are for that node.

In your theme add the following snippet and clear cache, refresh page, etc.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
   var_dump($vars['template_files']);
   //dsm($vars['template_files']); // if devel module installed
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time alex. I have added the code to my template.php but i am getting a white screen now across my website. I renamed it to function journalcrunch_preprocess etc (name taken from my info file) also tried function phptemplate_ as per some of the other code in my template but still the white screen of death. I have Devel installed if that helps at all?

Comment: Updated answer, its because your on v6.

Comment: lol k tx brb Alex :leaving

Comment: a brilliant Alex i think we've got there. the tpl name i was after is node-view-taxonomy_term-page_3.tpl.php I think we control the horizontal and the vertical now. I will keep that wee snippet to hand also as i like what it tells me. Ive a lot of node theming to learn in the next few weeks. Again thank you very much :)

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help Reg :-)

Comment: @RegGordon -- FWIW, try the module [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) if  you're doing a lot of theming. It's *super* useful for figuring template suggestions.

Comment: Thanks aendrew i will the now. I am starting to pick all this up i think. I remember about 7 years ago saying to a collegue 'that css thingy might be important in styling' and look at me now. Actually back to this now ive overridden my template i dont know what to put in it. errrrrr

Comment: bah i suppose this is now a differant question to what i asked as that has been solved. Ive tried many a thing in my new template but im either getting a wsod or im getting no rows at all.mmmmmm

Comment: a bingo i think im there. i just copied my node tpl in there and changed a few classes. sorted. tx again folks.